# How does casting from a void* of unique_ptr<T> to T** work?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, unique-ptr

I was surprised by the results I'm seeing in VC++ 2015, and need help understanding how it works.

```
struct MyType
{
  MyType(int x_) : x(x_) { }
  int x;
};

auto u = std::make_unique<MyType>(10);
void* pv = &u;
```

This obviously fails because `u`'s address is not a pointer to `MyType`:

```
MyType *pM = (MyType*)pv;
```

But this works, `pM2` gets the address of the `MyType` object stored in `u`:

```
MyType** ppM = (MyType**)pv;
MyType* pM2 = *ppM;
```

Is there anything in the standard that says this is supposed to work? Or is it only working due to a non-portable implementation detail of my compiler? Something that allows me to treat `unique_ptr` like a pointer-to-pointer in a round about way?

And before you say, "that's stupid, don't use `void*` or C-style casts", please understand that I'm working with legacy code that handles serialization of structs through void pointers and offsets to struct members. I can't change that part right now. But I want to use a `unique_ptr` for a struct member to simplify memory ownership and cleanup. And I'd like to know how fragile my `unique_ptr` is in this legacy environment.

Comment: Why don't you just do `MyType* pv = u.get();`? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get

Comment: What do you mean by *works/doesn't work* for each of the above? Are you trying to get a pointer to the object owned by the `unique_ptr` in each case? If yes, what's with the `MyType**` casts? Just use `void *pv = u.get();` A `unique_ptr` that has a stateless deleter, which yours does, typically contains just a pointer to the managed object, which is why your type punning seems to work.

Comment: You are just lucky because `std::unique_ptr` is likely a struct with a single pointer attribute, and it happens that the address of an object of type `std::unique_ptr` is the same as the address of the first attribute of this object, which is the pointer.

Comment: Ditch the unsafe C-style casts. If you *must* cast (always try *not* to), use C++ casts. But it's not even clear that what you really want is a cast.

Comment: The code I'm writing is not doing this casting/type punning. It is generic serialization code that does the C-style casts. It was made not made for smart pointers, It is legacy code that is not going to change in the near future. I just tried using a unique_ptr in a struct that goes through the serialization. From the answers so far, it sounds like I should stick with raw pointers and a destructor.

Comment: This happens to work because the representation of `unique_ptr` in memory, with the default deleter, is the same as a raw pointer, in common implementations.  Absolutely nothing guarantees that though, and furthermore there are probably aliasing issues even if the representation is given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically just you getting lucky.

In the ABI of your particular compiler, the `T*` that stores the object maintained by the `unique_ptr` is the first member of the object, so it has the same address as the object itself. In much the same way as this example:

```
struct container {
    int val;
};

int main() {
    container c{15};

    intptr_t val1 = reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(&c);
    intptr_t val2 = reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(&(c.val));

    assert(val1 == val2); //will pretty much always be true
}
```

Of course, **this is not behavior you should depend on!** It's unspecified by the Standard, and could change if the vendor decides they have a better format for storing pointers inside `std::unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you are doing something like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<MyType> up = ...;
MyType* p = *reinterpret_cast<MyType**>(&up);
```

With some detours and C-style casts. You take the pointer to the `unique_ptr` and reinterpret it as a pointer to pointer of `MyType`

This is pure luck and results in undefined behavior, you shouldn't use this type of code for any reason. If you need the internal pointer use the `get()` method on unique_ptr.

Comment: You are right. I tested my SSCCE on a couple of online compilers, and they behaved exactly the same as my VS2015, but in the end it is UB and should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

This is undefined behavior that happens to work because the unique pointer happens to store only a single pointer as its state, and that state is a pointer to `T`.

Undefined behavior can do anything, including time travel and format your hard drive.  I know people say this and others think it is a joke, but these are actually true statements you can experimentally verify.

As it happens, your undefined behavior here has reinterpreted some memory in a way that "works".

You cannot serialize/deserialize non-pod structures in a defined way using your library.  You can hack it to work, but any compiler update (even a compiler flag update!) could suddenly behave completely differently.

Consider having a structure for serialization/deserialization, and another for runtime use.  Marshall from one to the other.  Yes, this sucks.

Comment: I'm under the impression that the behavior here is *unspecified*, not *undefined*.

Comment: @Xirema Dereferencing a pointer to an object that isn't that object?  That triggers undefined behavior.  I suppose a particular unique ptr implementation could be standard layout with a prefix compatible with a `T*` and guaranteed by the compiler's standard library to be like that.